# Carriers in the channel of a MOSFET

Tags: mosfet

The channel formed in a MOSFET which is ON consists of carriers. From where do theses carriers come? Do they come from the Source/Drain regions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

They are pulled from the source as the potential difference between the gate and the source approaches its threshold. Just as in a classical capacitor, the larger the potential difference the more charges that get pulled into the channel.